# How to cleanup jbpm database from ended tasks

Tags: database, jbpm

I noticed that jbpm_byteblock has grown to few million rows and over GB.

Is there a way to remove rows related to ended tasks and proceses?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what version of jBPM you might be using.  But for jBPM 5.x, you can just remove tasks that are completed / aborted if you don't need them anymore.  This can be automated using a listener:

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-services/jbpm-human-task-services/src/main/java/org/jbpm/services/task/admin/listener/TaskCleanUpProcessEventListener.java